# Data driven subscription cascading parameters

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to setup a data-driven subscription and it works fine except when 2 of the parameters are set to take dynamic values instead of static ones.

The strucutre is basically

> Param1 -> read from database
>   Param2 -> read from database
>   Param3s -> read from database
>   Param3 -> split Param3s  (multivalued parameter, allowed values depend on Params 1 and 2)

Note that Param3 is a multi-value parameter and therefore it's value is populated by proxy from a string parameter (param3s) that is split.

The above does not work and gives the following error when saving the subscription

> This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'Param3'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet)

However, when setting Param1 and Param2 to static values it works.

There is nothing useful in the ReportServer logs to help in identifying what is going on.

Anyone have any clue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all parameters need to have a default value set to them, otherwise it won't work.

I had parameters 1 and 2 set without the default values in the report so it didn't work.